# How to `nc -l 1234 | bash` but send response back to connecter

Tags: shell, nc

I have a basic netcat listener on my network that uses this command: `nc -l 1234 | bash`. This command runs everything it receives in nc into BASh. It works, however, only the listener can see the outputs. How can I make the client able to see the output?

Comment: This might be better handled by `socat` or similar via `socat TCP-LISTEN:1234 EXEC:"bash -i",pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane,echo=0` and then using `nc` as a client to connect to that listener.

Comment: What's `socat`? I want this remote shell to use only things that come installed on the system.